# Exist a service like in android for windows phone 8?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, background, sensors, smartphone

I want to create a service like in android that is running in background always getting accelerometer data.

I searched for background Agent but I read that you can't get data from sensors but the info is not very clear.

There is something that can solve this problem?

thank you

Comment: Did you go through this sample? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Accelerometer-Sensor-Sample-22982671

Comment: Yes, I tried, and searching hard I found this :
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-sensors-eb7bb176
This is what I wanted but only for wp8.1
thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

All classes in the Microsoft.Devices.Sensors namespace are unsupported in background agents.  Source:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx

You can't do this.

Comment: I found that in WP8.1 is called Background Task and you can use some sensors